# jQuery scale and rotate animation with hover effect not working in Safari

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

Pretty much everything is animated with jQuery on my project. I am not using CSS3 animation. While testing I found out `hover` effect that performs `scale` and `rotate` is not functioning at all in Safari. Any ideas or suggestions ? 
One example:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="icons">
            <img src="images/icons/html_.png" width="5%" max-width: "100%" alt="HTML">

            <img src="images/icons/gulp_.png" width="5%" max-width: "100%" alt="Gulp">       

            </div> 
 </div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
    $('#icons').css({'perspective': '50px',
                'perspective-origin': '50% 50%'});
var gulpLogo = $('img[alt~="Gulp"]');
gulpLogo.hover(function() {
    $({rotateVar: 0}).animate(
    {
        rotateVar: 60
    },
    {
        duration: 8000,
        easing: 'easeOutElastic',
        step: function(now, abc){
            gulpLogo.css('transform', 'rotateY('+now+ 'deg)' );
        }
    } 
)
}, function() {
    $({rotateVar: 0}).animate(
    {
        rotateVar: 0
    },
    {
        duration: 8000,
        easing: 'easeOutElastic',
        step: function(now, abc){
            gulpLogo.css('transform', 'rotateY('+now+ 'deg)' );
        }
      } 
   )
});
```

Here is another one:

```
    $('img[alt~="HTML"]').hover(function() {
    duration: 5000,
      $(this).css('transform', 'scale(1.4)');
      }, 
      function() {
      $(this).css('transform', 'scale(1)');
    });
```

Comment: Use `-webkit-transform` for safari

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$('img[alt~="HTML"]').hover(function() {
      $(this).css('transform', 'scale(1.4)');
      $(this).css('-webkit-transform', 'scale(1.4)');
      }, 
      function() {
      $(this).css('transform', 'scale(1)');
      $(this).css('-webkit-transform', 'scale(1)');
    });
```

Comment: For some reasons with the example $('#icons').css({'perspective': '50px',
                'perspective-origin': '50% 50%'});   adding -webkit- makes it disappear on hover effect

Comment: Sorry don't know. Araise another question anybody will answer